# How to get client id for grid view from inside a view to use in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view that I want to use with JavaScript to calculate values entered in the textboxes.

I was adding `onkeyup` to the textboxes in the `onrowcreated` function and it was working fine.

Then I put the gridview in a `multiview`, and it stopped working.

This is my JavaScript function:

```
   function margin1(rowIndex, price, gridId) {
        var grid = document.getElementById(gridId);
        var volumeQuota = grid.rows[rowIndex].cells[2].innerText;
        alert(volumeQuota);
        var coef = grid.rows[rowIndex].cells[5].childNodes.item(1).value;
        alert(coef);
        var prevSites = grid.rows[rowIndex].cells[4].innerText;;
        grid.rows[rowIndex].cells[6].childNodes.item(1).value = parseFloat(coef) * (parseFloat(volumeQuota) - parseFloat(prevSites));
        grid.rows[rowIndex].cells[7].childNodes.item(1).value = price;

    }
```

and in the code behind this is how im adding it.

```
         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox t1 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("p98Margin1");
            t1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup",
                 string.Format("javascript:margin1('{0}', {1}, {2})", e.Row.RowIndex + 2,       a98.Text , GridView1.ClientID));
```

when I alert `Gridview1.clientId` in the JavaScript function I'm getting `[objectHTMLTableElement]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
   t1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup",
             string.Format("javascript:margin1('{0}', '{1}', '{2})'", e.Row.RowIndex + 2,       a98.Text , GridView1.ClientID));
```

I think this should work.
I think the value should go in single quotes `'` mark.

Comment: thanks it worked but like this margin1('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')",

Answer (score 0):

Like you said you put your grid in a multiview and everything stopped working,which means your gridview has been buried and you need to drill down a bit further to expose it.

Do this

```
 GridView myGridView=(GridView)(MultiView1.FindControl("GridView1"));
```

Now you have located it gracefully reference its ID

```
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TextBox t1 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("p98Margin1");
        t1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup",
             string.Format("javascript:margin1('{0}', {1}, {2})", e.Row.RowIndex + 2,       a98.Text ,myGridView.ClientID));
   }
```

Hope this helps.